# Static initialization by JVM

Tags: java, static-initialization

language: java
version: 12.0.2
String source code as follows:

```
 /* @implNote
 * The actual value for this field is injected by JVM. The static
 * initialization block is used to set the value here to communicate
 * that this static final field is not statically foldable, and to
 * avoid any possible circular dependency during vm initialization.
 */
static final boolean COMPACT_STRINGS;

static {
    COMPACT_STRINGS = true;
}
```

How to understand this sentence : 'The static initialization block is used to set the value here to communicate that this static final field is not statically foldable, and to avoid any possible circular dependency during vm initialization.'

Comment: Good question! This can be a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding  
But I have no idea about "circular dependency during vm initialization".

Comment: @Alex 75  In my idea, if they had written like this: 'static final boolean COMPACT_STRINGS = true'. It can still avoid any possible circular dependency, because 'COMPACT_STRINGS' has been given a determined  value. But it couldn't to avoid statically foldable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an implementation note for JVM implementers. It's not part of the public documentation and not of concern for developers that use `java.lang.String`.

But if you want to know:

Imagine that they had written:

```
static final boolean COMPACT_STRINGS = true;
```

Then it would have been a constant that the compiler could replace it with the value `true` wherever `COMPACT_STRINGS` was used (in the `java.lang` package only, because it's a package-local scoped variable)

By giving it the value `true` in a static initializer, the compiler doesn't know anymore that it's a constant and all code that uses it, has to look up the actual value that it has at runtime.

In this case, that is useful, because the JVM changes this value at runtime (even though it's `final`, the JVM can still change it), as the implementation note mentions.

Comment: can you explain the part `even though it's final, the JVM can still change it` on why JVM can change it? I got confuse on how JVM manages to change constant variables.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion It's the JVM that makes it final, and it can break the rules it sets for the applicaion.

Comment: @user207421 ahh then with some knowledge on JVM, it can also alter other variables?

Comment: The JVM can do it. There may be tricks using reflection and/or unsafe access that work in current JVM's that allows an application to do it, but these may (and will likely considering Oracle's direction)  no longer work in future versions of the JVM.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion The JVM can do whatever it likes.